# Symfony LiipImagineBundle Display image

Tags: php, symfony, twig, liipimaginebundle

Hi I'm using LiipImagineBundle to display an image in symfony web site.

I'm following this documentation: https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle

Here is the config.yml:

```
liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
        default:
            web_path: ~
    filter_sets:
        cache: ~
        news_detail:
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [800, 263], mode: outbound }
```

My image in my twig file:

```
<img src="{{ asset("uploads/media/" ~ news.imageName) | imagine_filter("news_detail") }}" alt="Image {{ news.title | capitalize }}">
```

My routing.yml:

```
_liip_imagine:
    resource: "@LiipImagineBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"
```

The config of the bundle generate this path (But this path does not exist):

`http://local.dev/media/cache/resolve/news_detail/uploads/media/test.jpg`

This path (bellow) works when I'm overriding the HTML with the inspector:

`http://local.dev/uploads/media/test.jpg`

I'm following the documentation but I don't understand why It does not work and what is the configuration of the cache system...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The bundle used the `exif`extension, so I had to install it in php.

I use docker so here is the solution with docker:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libexif-dev 
RUN docker-php-ext-install exif
```